# Symfony2 forms: call a method from another entity

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have two entity: User and Person. An user is a person and in the User entity I have a method getPerson().

Now I am trying to create a form in order to change th user profile.
In there, I would like to create:

```
$builder->add('degree', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'SciForumVersion2Bundle:Degree',
        'property' => 'degree',
));
$builder->add('person.firstname', 'text', array('required'=>true));
$builder->add('person.lastname', 'text', array('required'=>true));
$builder->add('person.address1', 'text', array('label'=>'Address', 'required'=>true));

ETC....
```

In the twig file, I have to use

```
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ form_label(form.degree) }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(form.degree) }}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    {{ form_label(form.firstname) }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(form.firstname, { 'attr': {'size': 30} }) }}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ form_label(form.lastname) }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(form.lastname, { 'attr': {'size': 30} }) }}
    </td>

ETC....
```

But for the

```
form.firstname
form.firstname
```

I am geting the exception:

```
Method "firstname" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in SciForumVersion2Bundle:User:changeProfile.html.twig at line 54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this problem. What I did is I created an extra entity called PersonUserEntity. In there, I have all the variables I need:

```
degree
firstname
lastname
address1
...ETC...
```

Then I am using this entity for the form.

Once the form submitted, I am getting information from this entity and populating the Person and the User entity separetly.

After that, I am using:

```
$em->persist($person);
$em->flush();

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a Person form within a User form you should take a look at [Embedded Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#embedded-forms) chapter in the symfony doc.

If you only want to show a Person form your code should work by removing the "person." part from field names, like this:

```
$builder->add('firstname', 'text', array('required'=>true));
$builder->add('lastname', 'text', array('required'=>true));
$builder->add('address1', 'text', array('label'=>'Address', 'required'=>true));
```

Comment: Thank you very much @dasouza, creating a Person form within a User form is exactly what I need. I will try to use their example in my case. When done, I will accept your answer.